# Convert integer array to unsigned char array

Tags: c

I have storage a "bits" in integer array for example

```
int a = {1,0,1,1}
```

How I will be able to convert the integer array "bits" into unsigned char "bits"?

and reciprocal?

Comment: What do you mean with "integer array bits"?

Comment: not clear for me. Do you want to convert `{1,0,1,1}` to `unsigned char` e.g, unsigned char x = 1011; or its binary representation?

Comment: Your sample shouldn't compile without a severe warning, if at all.

Answer (score 3):

```
int int_array[] = {1, 0, 1, 1};
unsigned char uc_array[sizeof int_array / sizeof *int_array];
for (size_t i = 0; i != sizeof int_array / sizeof *int_array; ++i)
  uc_array[i] = int_array[i];
```

(Your sample code is flawed: it has too many initializers for a scalar variable)

Comment: "Your sample code is flawed: it has too many initializers for a scalar variable" not understand, why is wrong?

Comment: @Juan: Because it should be `int a[]`.